# Cannot import app service certificate (ASC) to Azure web-app through Azure portal due to permissions issue

Tags: azure, ssl, azure-web-app-service

When I try to import my ASC certificate to a web app, I get the following error:

```
Failed to add App Service certificate to the app, Check error for more details. Error Details: The service does not have access to 'path to key vault' Key Vault. Please make sure that you have granted necessary permissions to the service to perform the request operation.
```

I've granted my account "owner" level admin of all my resources.

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Key Vault uses services principals for authentication when an access policy is assigning, ensure that the application is registered on Azure in order to generate a valid Service Principal for access policies. Are you using any cmdlet for importing the certificate? 
I just tried the import operation (same process) via the Portal, and it seem to work fine.

[image]

Take a look the document - az keyvault certificate import https://learn.microsoft.com/cli/azure/keyvault/certificate?view=azure-cli-latest#az-keyvault-certificate-import) - Authorization in Key Vault uses a combination of Role based access control (RBAC) and Azure Key Vault access policies.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I didn’t use either the Azure Powershell or the Cloud Shell. I tried doing it all in the portal. Did you have any special permissions set up?